# Expo & OneSignal Issues on Mac M1 Pro

Tags: react-native, expo, onesignal, react-native-onesignal

I'm hoping someone can help. I'm following the documentation to the letter here: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-expo-sdk-setup

And no matter what I do, even build a completely fresh project and try from there, I get:

```
Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null.
```

Has anyone experienced this, and been able to solve it? See screenshot of the error below:

[image: Screenshot of error.]